# How to plot a graph with the column plot between the axis

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, charts

How to plot graph in c# between 2 axis like below:

[image]

This is my graph using chart control in c# with visual studio:

[image]

I want to plot the column series between the two axes without the 1st column being cut to the left.

The chart settings:

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsMarginVisible = false;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your settings are wrong.

Especially setting [`IsMarginVisible = false;`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.ismarginvisible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) makes the column slide to the left and half of it gets cut off. So delete that line and stay with the default of `true`!

Additionally you will want to add an [Offset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.intervaloffset(v=vs.110).aspx) to the Interval, so it doesn't start labelling the axis at a negative value..:

```
Axis ax = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
ax.Interval = 1;
ax.IntervalOffset = 1;
```

[image]

**Update:** If you actually want to remove the gaps you should set the series to be indexed:

```
yourSeries.IsXValueIndexed = true;
```

[MSDN on this:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.series.isxvalueindexed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Remarks
>
> All data points in a series use sequential indices, and if this
>   property is true then data points will be plotted sequentially,
>   regardless of their associated X-values. This means that there will be
>   no "missing" data points.
>
> For example, assume there are three (3) data points in a series having
>   X-values of 1, 2 and 4. If this property was false, there would be a
>   data point missing at the X-axis location labeled "3". However, if you
>   set this property to true, the three data points will be plotted at
>   points 1, 2, and 4, sequentially, and there will be no missing data
>   point. The X-axis location labeled "3" will not appear on the chart.
>
> This is useful when you do not want to have missing data points for
>   intervals that you know you will not have data for, such as weekends.
>
> If you are displaying multiple series and at least one series uses
>   indexed X-values, then all series must be aligned—that is, have the
>   same number of data points—and the corresponding points must have the
>   same X-values.

Do take special care to understand the last paragraph, especially if you want to use some stacked chart!

One alternative to using the `IsXValueIndexed` setting is inserting empty datapoints at the gaps. Best do it by using the [`DataPoint.IsEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456677.aspx) property.

Comment: thanks @TaW. I removed the `IsMarginVisible` just now add set the `IntervalOffset = 1`. The result return the same. The column remain at the same place.

Comment: It works fine here, as you can see. You need to tell us more about the x-values. Type? Are they numbers or dates? Or are they strings? How did you set the interval? Also: Axis.minimum,maximum?

Comment: I want the column chart plot between the the mark/axes. See the first picture in my actual post. I hope the figure will tell you the actual need. Btw, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: If you want to __remove the gaps__: see my update. Sorry but I really didn't understand; still not sure. It is imortant to use different words when explaining a second time, not the same that were not understood/clear before.. You may want to reverse parts of my edit of the question..!?

Answer (score 0):

I think, my try and error found the solution. This what I have done:

```
// Create some null data point with integer value
DataPoint nulldp1 = new DataPoint();
nulldp1.SetValueXY(1, 0);

DataPoint nulldp2 = new DataPoint();
nulldp2.SetValueXY(2, 0);

chart.Series["SeriesName"].Points.Add(nulldp1);
chart.Series["SeriesName"].Points.Add(nulldp2);


// Plotting the chart
double index = 0.5;
foreach (var item in items)
{
    // The data point for each series
    DataPoint dp = new DataPoint();
    dp.XValue = index;
    dp.SetValueY(item.Percentage);

    chart.Series[item.Name].Points.Add(dp);

    index++;
}
```

I don't know either this solution is OK or not. But, eventually it solved my problem.

Comment: A workaround; shouldn't be necessary here, but if it works, ok.

Comment: The empty data point is the solution for gap shown on the 1st picture. I just decorate my code to make sure the need from the requirement is fulfill first. While i'm still newbie in C#, i don't know if my action is the best. My post here just seeking for expertise like you here. Anyway, thanks @TaW for your replies.